# How to put icon in a datagrid view in C# .net 4.0 windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to have icons in a column of a datagridview in C# .net 4.0 windows form application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the answer from @leppie and your comments i would suggest the following:

Create a UserControl that shows the image and some text. Take care that it will look good, regardless the size of the control (since some MinimumSize) by using Anchoring, Docking, FlowLayoutPanel, whatever.

After successfully creating your own control that is capable of holding some text AND a image, take [this tutorial from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881.aspx) and put your UserControl into it as DataGridViewUserControlColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same as .NET 3.5.

Just use an Image column.

Comment: Actually I need to put Image with text in that column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you getting text and a image. You will probably have to resort making your own custom `DataGridViewColumn`.